# How can I debug a "Failed to install" message?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I am currently attempting to develop a cross-platform mobile app using Xamarin.forms.  As a part of this application I need to include a 3rd party .framework in my Xamarin.iOS project. I have successfully created a Xamarin.iOS Bindings Library .dll and included it in my project. I am able to reference the library and compile without errors, however when I attempt to deploy the app to the iPhone simulator the app will start and then crash with a “Failed to install” message.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d88ek.png)

If I remove any lines of code which reference this .dll the app will run fine.

Does anyone have any insight on how to solve this?

Potentially useful information:
I am developing in Visual Studio for Windows
Xamarin version: 16.7.000.440
Xamarin.iOS version: 13.20.2.2
XCode version: 12.0.1
iOS version: 14.0

Device Crash Log:

```
Incident Identifier: 882D82AB-5511-48C1-AFCD-4B86933B2A5C  
CrashReporter Key:   1cc59f0bc819c0d806e2c1ccdf7b24a413699a4f  
Hardware Model:      iPad7,11  
Process:             MyApp.iOS [452]  
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A31E102C-4BB8-431A-ABDF-E17A503E1778/MyApp.iOS.app/MyApp.iOS  
Identifier:          com.Crossroads.MyApp  
Version:             1.0 (1.0)  
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)  
Role:                Foreground  
Parent Process:      launchd [1]  
Coalition:           com.Crossroads.MyApp [614]  


Date/Time:           2020-10-16 09:46:53.9542 -0500  
Launch Time:         2020-10-16 09:46:53.9106 -0500  
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)  
Release Type:        User  
Baseband Version:    n/a  
Report Version:      104  

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)  
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000  
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY  
Termination Description: DYLD, dependent dylib '@rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework' not found for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A31E102C-4BB8-431A-ABDF-E17A503E1778/MyApp.iOS.app/MyApp.iOS', tried but didn't find: '@rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework' '/System/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework'  
Highlighted by Thread:  0  

Backtrace not available  

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):  
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x000000016b701390   x3: 0x00000000000000c7  
    x4: 0x000000016b700f90   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000  
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x6f4d706163617461  x11: 0x656b6f54656c6962  
   x12: 0x6f77656d6172662e  x13: 0x63617461442f6b72  x14: 0x656c69626f4d7061  x15: 0x0020276e656b6f54  
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000  
   x20: 0x000000016b700f90  x21: 0x00000000000000c7  x22: 0x000000016b701390  x23: 0x0000000000000001  
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x0000000106cd4000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000106cd4000  
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016b700f60   lr: 0x0000000106cbbee8  
    sp: 0x000000016b700f20   pc: 0x0000000106cb4f68 cpsr: 0x00000000  
   esr: 0x00000000  Address size fault  

Binary images description not available  

Error Formulating Crash Report:  
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  

EOF
```

Comment: Can you please check the device log for more error information?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I've added the crash log to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_missing_framework_crashes?language=objc), the errors means you have linked the frame while does not ember it.

> The app crashes at launch, because the dynamic linker can’t locate the
> missing framework.

So what you need to do is ember the framework and here is the document you can refer:

[Linking the dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=windows#linking-the-dependencies)

[binding-objective-c](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/)

Comment: Turns out the problem was in my binding .dll. I was referencing the MyFramework.a in the .linkswith.cs instead of the MyFramework.framework.